# Data format needs to follow between BLE profile and iPad in order to transfer data

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Please guide me that, What is the data format needs to follow between BLE profile and iPad in order to transfer data.

I am performing both update(read) and write operation to BLE components from my iPad application.

Thanks in advance for the quick answer!!!

Comment: I need to know whether we need to use json format or xml format or some other format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to check out the following guide.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

this should give you some hints about how to communicate with bluetooth devices.

Comment: Thanks...But this is not I am looking for. I need to know whether we need to use json format or xml format or some other format.